# Get_contents and Put_contents on image, how to save all formats?

Tags: php

I use the following code, but what happens when the target image is not a jpg ?
How can I make sure that any format will be saved correctly?

`myimage` will be `myimage[$i]` because I will save a lot of images.

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://anothersite/images/goods.jpg");
file_put_contents(YOUR_DIRECTORY."myimage.jpg",$content);
```

Comment: So you want to extract the extension from `"http://anothersite/images/goods.jpg"`? That can be done using [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo). If you just have content, there’s [`exif_imagetype`](http://php.net/exif_imagetype).

Comment: @minitech exactly, but in some cases the image may be .gif. Can you point me to this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the extension from the source path using [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$info = pathinfo("http://anothersite/images/goods.jpg");
$destination = YOUR_DIRECTORY . "myimage.{$info['extension']}";
```

Comment: I believe the poster want more than just an extension, but a correct extension. For example. goods.jpg extension might be .jpg, but the content of the file is .gif extension.

Comment: @invisal the filetype may be anything. I will get some images from a website that contains .jpg .png and gif.

Comment: @invisal: [I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288018/get-contents-and-put-contents-on-image-how-to-save-all-formats/17288065?noredirect=1#comment25065703_17288018), but the question seems to be to copy the extension on the source path. If not, I’ll add the right thing. =)